# Set width and margin of only the chart in Highcharts in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Im trying to make my Highcharts pie chart fully responsive to work on small mobile devices with a resolution of minimum 320px.

On the chart container i have set a minimum width of 320px but still the chart looks so messy on small mobile devices because the width is taken including the legend.

[image]

Even the chart responsive options are been set, It doesnt work because it takes the complete container width

```
 responsive: {
  rules: [{
    condition: {
      maxWidth: 500,
      minWidth: 320
    },
    chartOptions: {
      legend: {
        enabled: true,
         itemStyle: {
                 font: '9pt Open Sans, Verdana, sans-serif',
                 color: '#A0A0A0'
              },
      },

    }
  }]
},
```

You can check the fiddle over here http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/a3qfv4fw/6/

If i set the chart width and a margin inside the chart settings it works, but i want to apply this only when the responsive rules are been called

```
chart: {
       width: 320,
       marginLeft: 190,
       },
```

Can someone tell me how can i include the chart `Width` and `margin` only for the chart excluding the legend on small resolutions?

Comment: Do you have a picture of how your chart should look like on small devices? What should happen with the legend? You can try to manipulate with the pie.size or pie.minSize properties http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.minSize

Comment: @morganfree what i need is to wrap the legend text so the `extended ` word goes to the next line and the chart to fit into that space, with  a small sized chart and small text on the pie http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/a3qfv4fw/7/